# CS50: pset8 finance: How to extract float "cash" value from SQL table users?

Tags: finance, cs50

I'm working in buy. I need to compare the available cash of the user with the price of the stock they want to purchase. I try extracting the cash value from my SQL database and what I get is a dictionary inside a list, not the numeric value.

I would need to extract only the numeric value as a float. As later, I need to compare it with a float in Python. Here is the query that I execute and I save the result in a variable called cash:

```
cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
```

As a result, this is what I get:

```
[{'cash': 10000}]
```

An additional question is, why am I getting what looks like a dictionary inside a list?

Can someone please shed some light? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally extracted the desired piece of data. I have, first, executed my SQL query and saved its result, the dict inside the list, in one variable, called "row":

```
row = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
```

And, after that, I have stored in a new variable "cash" the appropriate value inside my dict, the value whose key is "cash":

```
cash = float(row[0]["cash"])
```

So, now I have my desired value stored in a variable called "cash" as a float.